# Multiple null checks using Optional in Java 8

Tags: java, datetime, if-statement, java-8, option-type

I want to simplify the below piece of code with multiple `if` and `else` statements using Java 8. 
Is there a way to get rid of them altogether using some Java 8 feature, e.g. `Optional`?
I tried to find something here but couldn't find an answer.

```java
LocalDateTime beDate = someDate;
LocalDateTime aeDate = someDate;
LocalDateTime eDate;

if (beDate == null && aeDate == null) {
    eDate = null;
}
else if (beDate != null && aeDate == null) {
    eDate = beDate;
}
else if (beDate == null && aeDate != null) {
    eDate =  aeDate;
}
else if (beDate != null && aeDate != null && 
        (beDate.isEqual(aeDate) || beDate.isBefore(aeDate))) {
    eDate = beDate;
}
else {
    eDate = aeDate;
}
```

Comment: I think you should less care about if you can simplify with ```Optional``` but about what to simplify in general. And please use braces.

Comment: @akuzminykh, edited the code with braces, sorry about that. This is the check that is required. Not sure if I can simplify it further.

Comment: I would suggest you to have nested if-s, outer checks one date, inner checks another one. I also feel like you could extract some code as reusable method

Comment: I think first three checks can be replaced with LocalDateTime eDate = Optional.ofNullable(beDate).orElse(aeDate); You can go on with the approach. Hint: check the other methods of Optional

Comment: @IliaNedoluzhko Not quite, since that formulation wouldn't pick the earlier if both were present.

Comment: Exactly, but you could use that as a starting point :)

Comment: @Pi53 You should use the right tool. I doubt `Optional` is a good choice for this particular case. I'd go with `ObjectUtils::min` from Apache Commons. Much more concise and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The logic here is very difficult to understand. Instead, express your intention more directly:

```
private static final Comparator<ChronoLocalDateTime<?>> EARLIEST_PRESENT = 
    Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder());

LocalDateTime eDate = BinaryOperator.minBy(EARLIEST_PRESENT).apply(beDate, aeDate);
```

(Note that static imports for the elements from `Comparator` and `BinaryOperator` will make this even clearer.)

Comment: It's a good answer but kinda feels overkilled. Anyways, it's exactly what OP asked for.

Comment: @akuzminykh Understandability to humans is possibly the most important goal in code. It took me almost a full minute to figure out what OP's code was intended to do.

Comment: Was this the end of the strike? :-)

Comment: @OleV.V. We'll see. I don't see myself hitting multiple daily limits anytime soon.

Comment: Or `return BinaryOperator.minBy(EARLIEST_PRESENT).apply(beDate, aeDate);` though I prefer [a single expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60753142/2711488) in this case...

Comment: Thanks @chrylis-onstrike-. Trying to refactor code which is at least a decade old. Didn't really look at the logic behind the code of getting the minimum non null element. Still new to Java 8 so your answer helped a lot. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, @Holger; I didn't think of `minBy` for the special case of two options and have updated the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Your conditions are redundant, given that the result is only one of two possible outcomes:

```
if (beDate == null && aeDate == null) {
    eDate = null;
}
else if (beDate != null && aeDate == null) {
    eDate = beDate;
}
...
```

Here, `eDate` will have the same contents as `beDate` in either case, whether `null` or not. So `if(aeDate == null) eDate = beDate;` would be sufficient. In all other cases, you're assigning `aeDate`, with only one exception:

```
...
else if (beDate != null && aeDate != null && 
        (beDate.isEqual(aeDate) || beDate.isBefore(aeDate))) {
    eDate = beDate;
}
...
```

We can simplify `beDate.isEqual(aeDate) || beDate.isBefore(aeDate)` to `aeDate.isAfter(beDate)`.

So the entire statement can be written as:

```
LocalDateTime eDate
    = aeDate == null || (beDate != null && aeDate.isAfter(beDate))? beDate: aeDate;
```

The `||` is short-circuiting, which means, the right hand side is only evaluated when the left hand side evaluated to `false`, so when the left hand side is `aeDate == null`, it is implied for the right hand side that `aeDate != null` and doesn't need to be repeated.

So `eDate` will get the value of `beDate` when `aeDate` is `null` (the first two `if` statements) or when both are not `null` and `aeDate` is after `beDate` (the other cited `if` statement), and get the value of `aeDate` otherwise.

The operator precedence makes the brackets unnecessary, but it's also valid to keep them for clarity.

Comment: Trying to refactor old code and didn't really look at the logic behind the code. Whatever you said definitely makes sense and should've been checked previously.Thanks for your help but will be going with the solution provided by @chrylis-on-strike-

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Optional.ofNullable`, but I do not recommend that.

Wrapping everything in `Optional` won't make it easier to read. You have to make a `null` check, so you're replacing `obj == null` with `obj.isEmpty()` (or `obj.isEmpty()` in java 8).

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to get rid of the many if else statements. Is there?

Comment: @Pi53 not that I know of. It is not the purpose of `Optional`.

Comment: The null check isn't strictly necessary; OP is just reinventing `Comparator.nullsLast()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [ObjectUtils::min](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/ObjectUtils.html#min(java.lang.Comparable,%20java.lang.Comparable)) from Apache Commons:

```
LocalDateTime eDate = ObjectUtils.min(aeDate, beDate);
```

The solution is one liner and easy to read.